# React seamless expand product card to fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, framer-motion

I am building a single page e-commerce app. The products page is based on cards in a responsive grid. I want to make a card to expand `onClick` to fullscreen with something like `spring` or `ease` animation to see full product page.

The problem is the card is tied to the grid and is not always in center. And everything I tried to do with css animations looked awful from animations perspective and felt like a bicycle from code perspective.

I just wanted to ask, what in short is the best way to achieve this, what path should I choose? And is it really possible with grid I have now, or I should try something different? I thought of using `Framer Motion` as an animation library.

Here you can see something similar to what I want to achieve: https://youtu.be/XyBbFMhMtik?t=10

And here is simplified **codesandbox** of what I have now: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-water-o2lpp

[image: Sample]

Comment: I would imagine you could use double container =: one for placeholder, one for contents, and apply an fixed position to contents, making it independent of the wrapper and expand it to full screen with ether css or javascript or jquery. what have you tried ?

Comment: @DmitriyGodlevski I tried applying higher z-index and setting card to 100vh and 100vw, but the animation was not synchronous between all variables and the look was bad.
I forked `Framer Motion` example and made something similar, but it does not solve the non centered div and border radius for now - https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-side-menu-6dub3
What you mean by container and placeholder? You mean to make a card div and a div child for card content?

Comment: @DmitriyGodlevski I guess I found something similar to my needs, if it would be possible to adapt it to my needs - https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animatesharedlayout-app-store-demo-su6mx

Comment: I spouse it might, ** nothing good ever comes out of external sandboxes questions. Usually they ship with 'problem is unclear', 'my misunderstanding is general and not specific', 'looking for something to plug up the hole and be fullfiled'. ** Happy hacking.